# Read IDataReader on a GROUP BY MySQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, group-by

I have a table "nesting_bar_detail", that I read like that in my C# code :

```
public List<RepereNest> SelectListRepereNestInMeb(string query)
{
    List<RepereNest> list = new List<RepereNest>();
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        IDataReader dataReader = ExecuteReader(query);
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            RepereNest det = new RepereNest();
            det.ID=(long)dataReader["ID"];
            det.IdDetail=(long)dataReader["ID_DETAIL"];
            det.IdNesting=(long)dataReader["ID_NESTING"];
            det.Name = (string)dataReader["NAME"];
            det.Quantity = (int)dataReader["QUANTITY"];
            list.Add(det);
        }
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
    return list;
}
```

If I make a simple query, as here, all is working fine

SELECT * FROM nesting_bar_detail WHERE NAME='TITI'

But when I want to group the results, I make the following request :

```
SELECT ID,ID_DETAIL,ID_NESTING, NAME, SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY GROUP BY ID_DETAIL,ID_NESTING ORDER BY ID_NESTING
```

But then I have an error on the lines where I "calculate" the field (in that case on the line `det.Quantity = (int)dataReader["QUANTITY"];`, that is a SUM)

Error "The specified cast is invalid"

I don't understand if this my SQL request that is not correct, or why the returned value type is not recognized ?

**Edit :**

Here is the data I have inside database :

```
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
| ID    | ID_DETAIL | ID_NESTING | NAME | QUANTITY |
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
| 10754 | 10        | 58         | TITI | 2        |
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
| 10755 | 11        | 59         | TITI | 3        |
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
| 10756 | 11        | 59         | TITI | 4        |
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
```

And here is Expected result :

```
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
| ID    | ID_DETAIL | ID_NESTING | NAME | QUANTITY |
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
| 10754 | 10        | 58         | TITI | 2        |
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
| 10755 | 11        | 59         | TITI | 7        |
+-------+-----------+------------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Also you should read how to use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) as most likely you are not using it correctly..

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland excuse me but what you mean? If you are talking about some fields missing, I specially remove one part of the query, because it was very long to read.

Comment: `SELECT ID, ID_NESTING, IS_SUBDETAIL, NAME, ID_DETAIL, ID_CONTRACT, CONTRACT, PHASE, ASSEMBLY .... GROUP BY ID_DETAIL,ID_NESTING`  is invalid GROUP BY usage ... -> *"SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause"*

Comment: .. unless you are using MySQL 5.7.5+ with enabled sql_mode only_full_group_by then a exception rule from SQL:1999 which is called functional dependency to overrule that SQL 92 rule

Comment: @RaymondNijland using MySQL 5.7.26, but agree with you that I may adapt to any version. Anyway if I understand good this is a problem linked to `only_full_group_by`, I already had issues in past with it(already saw your link many times), but I believed I finally understood it... seems not.

Comment: *"using MySQL 5.7.26"* Use `SELECT @@sql_mode` to check if `only_full_group_by` is in there if it is you can fully trust on functional dependency  and forgot all about mine comments :-)

Comment: Well, first as you advised, I edited the post and made request even shorter so easier to understand.Then I tried your request, and I got that as result : `STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERR...` Seems there is something after(...), but cannot open it. about "only_full_group_by", what would be the best thing to do?not just to make it work, but as experimented developper what would you advise?

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok then after re-reading your link, if I understood I may add all required fields in the `GROUP`? no way to do it an easier way? (As I have around 30 fields, would be very long query)

Comment: See mine second comment about making a Minimal Reproducible Example ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok, I believed that was enough as I did... will try this `ASCII data table generator tool` then come back when I could do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201257/discussion-between-siegfried-v-and-raymond-nijland).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

"The SUM() and AVG() functions return a DECIMAL value for exact-value arguments (integer or DECIMAL), and a DOUBLE value for approximate-value arguments (FLOAT or DOUBLE)."

In your C# code you're trying to cast the resulting DECIMAL value of SUM(QUANTITY) as an `int`

Comment: Is there a way to force to return an `int` in SQL? In fact I use the same function to return grouped, and non grouped objects. Until now the way I found to solve it is to make something as `det.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["QUANTITY"].ToString());` but not very beautiful...

Comment: Perhaps FLOOR(SUM(QUANTITY)) in the query?

Comment: not working too, well I think I will keep this "not so beautiful" solution I put in comment, I have the same issue on `0 AS OVERMEASURE`(overmeasure supposed to be a double), thanks anyway this helped a lot to understand that. Just thought about, the other option is making grouping in code instead of SQL, will avoid that ugly code...